# scp doesn't work when I use sshpass with password

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, scp, file-server

I am trying to transfer files between my file server and raspberry pi, I can't figure out why this doesn't work

When I run this in the terminal it works:

```bash
scp "/home/testfile.txt" pi@10.51.112.139:"/home/pi"
```

But this doesn't work:

```bash
sudo sshpass -p "Blueberry89" scp "/home/testfile.txt" pi@10.51.112.139:"/home/pi"
```

there isn't any output from the command either

I have tried this both ways, on my server and the pi, neither worked. I'm sure it's just something really little, but I can't find out whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the trouble turned out to be using `sudo` at the same time as `sshpass`.  When the command:

```
sshpass -p "Blueberry89" scp "/home/testfile.txt" pi@10.51.112.139:"/home/pi"
```

was tried, it worked fine.  (It's very likely `sudo` was parsing the rest of the command line and misinterpreting the options/arguments as its own)